# Not able to Generate MYSQL Query Dynamically

Tags: php, mysql

Following mysqli query not working. I need to assign SET variable value to blink ' ' space or null. But problem is after SET if i use any variable then it not working. Please tell me whats wrong i am doing with this query?

```
$q = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE photo_gallery 
                          SET $name_of_image_to_del=' ' 
                          WHERE id='$row_id'");
```

Comment: check the value is their or not in $name_of_image_to_del

Comment: $name_of_image_to_del i have to use variable here. coz i dont have any fixed value for that.

Comment: Is the variable an actual name of the column?

Comment: the variable value is a column name

Comment: Echo the query, then run it directly in the database. Do you get an error? Also check for mysqli_error() after your query.

Comment: If you add some error proecessing, then MYSQL will probably tell you what you have done wrong addd this line after your `mysqli_query()` like so `if(!$q){ echo mysqli_error($conn); exit;}`

Comment: Alternatively add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of all your scripts while developing and that will make MYSQL throw an exception that you just cannot ignore when something goes wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check the value is present and after that you pass in that query:-

```
if (isset($name_of_image_to_del) && $name_of_image_to_del != '') {
    $q = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE photo_gallery SET $name_of_image_to_del=' ' WHERE id='$row_id'");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to update a value of a columnName which is Dynamic,

Please find Below code for the same :

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","db");
    $columnName = 'columnName';
    $valueToCheck = 'makeMeBlank';
    $sql = "UPDATE tableName SET $columnName=' ' WHERE id='$valueToCheck'";
    $q = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
```